# How to find $A$ from $Ax=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, definition, systems-of-equations, regularization

I am aware of the inverse problem of the form $Ax=b$ where matrix $A$ and vector $b$ are known and we need to estimate the vector $x$. Is there any formal methods to find matrix $A$ given $b$ and $x$? I can understand how ill-posed it may be, but is there any studies about it?

Specifically, is there specific significance of matrix $A$ with highest $L_p$ norm, or sparsest matrix $A$ or even $A$ with specified singular values?

Comment: It is easy enough to find _some_ $A$ such that $Ax=b$ (unless $x$ is the zero vector and $b$ is nonzero): Just pick a column that corresponds to a nonzero component of $x$, and write the components of $b$ (divided by that component of $x$) in that column, and let the rest of the entries in $A$ be zero. You just won't have any guarantee that the result is even close to the $A$ someone else might be thinking about with the same property.

Comment: In general, there are several choices for $A$. For this reason it does not seem too interesting to look for formal methods to find an $A$. Sometimes you can just guess, or take $A=0$, if $x=0$ or $b=0$. To find $x$ with given $A$ and $b$ certainly is more interesting.

Comment: The matrix $A$ has $mn$ unknown coefficients and you only provide $m$ equations. So this problem is highly underdetermined.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you for your interest, yes, so wondering out of all those possible solution does any of the extreme has any significance.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised that the $L_p$ norm can be arbitrarily high. And a solution with a single non-zero column is always possible.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a linear system (underdetermined) in the coefficients $A_{ij}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have a linear system in $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$

$$\mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b$$

where $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $\mathrm b \in \mathbb R^{m}$ are given. [Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) the left-hand side, we obtain the linear system

$$(\mathrm x^T \otimes \mathrm I_m) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A) = \mathrm b$$

which is written in a more familiar form. We have $m n$ unknowns and only $m$ equations, i.e., if $n > 1$ then we have an **underdetermined** linear system. The null space of $\mathrm x^T \otimes \mathrm I_m$ has dimension at least $m (n-1)$. Assuming that $n > 1$, then there are infinitely many solutions.

We can search for the matrix $\mathrm A$ with the **minimum Frobenius norm** via $2$-norm minimization

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|\mbox{vec} (\mathrm A)\|_2\\ \text{subject to} & (\mathrm x^T \otimes \mathrm I_m) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A) = \mathrm b\end{array}$$

or we can search for a **sparse** matrix $\mathrm A$ via $1$-norm minimization

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|\mbox{vec} (\mathrm A)\|_1\\ \text{subject to} & (\mathrm x^T \otimes \mathrm I_m) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A) = \mathrm b\end{array}$$

In MATLAB, use function `kron` to do the Kronecker product $\otimes$ and `reshape` to vectorize (and un-vectorize).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is surely a diagonal matrix A whose diagonal elements can immediately be computed - when no zeros in $x$ are involved.

However, if zeros in $b$ or in $x$ are involved $A$ may not be possible to make diagonal.

In some extreme case: where $b$ is completely zero but not $x$, then a special solution would be needed; for instance that $A$ is so, that $x$ is an eigenvector of $A+ \lambda \cdot I$