# Solving $b=Ax$ with matrix $A$ unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, constraints

I have the following problem:

> Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}^{k+1}$ with known integer values and $b(k+1)=1$.

*Note*: If it makes it easier, let $k<n$

I need to find a matrix $X$ with integer values such that $a=Xb$ and it satisfies following restrictions $$\forall i,j\quad X(i,j) \geq 0 , \forall j<k+1:\sum_{i} X(i,j) \leq n_{j}$$ with each $n_{j}$ also a known integer (so the sum of each column is restricted). Furthermore I want to minimize the sum of the last column.

Note that I reduced a problem at work to this statement and don't recall ever studying such a problem during my times at university (I haven't done much math since then). I also didn't find anything interesting on the internet. Is this even possible to solve?

Comment: $a = Ab$ is horrible notation.

Comment: Pick letters from the end of the Latin alphabet for unknowns.

Comment: Ok, since only the matrix is unknown, I called it X.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956943/339790)

Comment: What you have is an [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem.  If $n$ and $k$ are not too large, there is available software that can solve it.

Comment: Is it really an integer linear programming problem if it is the matrix that is to be defined?

Comment: Or should I use the vectorization, as is linked by Rodrigo?

Comment: Pick the smallest toy example that is interesting.  Vectorize and obtain an underdetermined system of linear Diophantine equations.  You can then use IP or something else.  You could probably use something like the [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form).

Comment: This seems like a good lead, I will look into at work tommorow. Thank you.